# Difference of two complex polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that for any integer $m>1$, $(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}z^2+a^2\cot^2{\frac{k\pi}{2m}}$

I started off by expanding the left hand side using the binomial therem and noticed that some terms cancelled out and I ended up with the expression below for the LHS

$2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}$$2m\choose{2k-1}$$z^{2m-2k+1}$$a^{2k-1}$

I am stuck as to where to go past this. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are supposed to find the roots of the polynomial $P(z) = (z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}$

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: By solving $|z+a|^{2m} = |z-a|^{2m}$ and $\text{arg}((z+a)^{2m})= \text{arg}((z-a)^{2m})+2i\pi$. Alternatively, by solving $u^{2m} = 1$ and using the change of variable $u = \frac{z+a}{z-a}$

Comment: @reuns Ok so i found that $z=a(\frac{e^{frac{i\pi}{k}+1}{\frac{e^{frac{i\pi}{k}-1}$

Comment: @reuns what do I do after I have found the roots

Comment: Do I express the polynomial in factored form

Comment: Yes. How many roots did you find ? What is the degree of your polynomial ? Do you recognize the roots ?

Comment: M roots I think

Comment: If you are not sure, write everything clearly, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

We follow the comments and consider the polynomial
\begin{align*}
u^{2m}=1\qquad\text{ with roots }\qquad \exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}{m}\right), 1\leq k\leq 2m
\end{align*}

The function
\begin{align*}
u(z)=\frac{z-a}{z+a}
\end{align*}
has the inverse function
\begin{align*}
z(u)=-a\frac{u+1}{u-1}
\end{align*}

> We conclude the roots of the equation
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{z-a}{z+a}\right)^{2m}=1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   are if $-m+1\leq k\leq m-1$
>   \begin{align*}
> -a\cdot\frac{\exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}{m}\right)+1}{\exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}{m}\right)-1}
> =-ai\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}{2m}\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{k \pi i}{2m}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{2i}\left(\exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}{2m}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{k \pi i}{2m}\right)\right)}
> =ia\cot \frac{k\pi}{2m}
> \end{align*}
>   together with the root $z=0$.

We can now write (1) in polynomial form and as product of factors

> \begin{align*}
> (z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}&=Az\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left[\left(z-ia\cot \frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\left(z+ia\cot \frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\right]\\
> &=Az\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot ^2\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   with $A$ constant.

In order to determine $A$ it is convenient to calculate the coefficient of $z^{2m-1}$, denoted with $[z^{2m-1}]$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
[z^{2m-1}]&\left((z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}\right)
=\binom{2m}{2m-1}a-\binom{2m}{2m-1}(-a)=4ma\\
[z^{2m-1}]&Az\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot ^2\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)=A
\end{align*}

We finally obtain with $A=4ma$

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot ^2\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}
> \end{align*}